# Windows KMDF self-signing

Tags: windows, 64-bit, driver, kmdf

Is it possible to **self-signing** a windows kernel driver?

I read many posts and websites on this topic and some said yes, others say no. For me, i was not able to self sign a kernel driver with following aspects:

- Secure Boot is enabled
- `TESTSIGNING OFF` (the text on desktop is hidden at right bottom)
- The `sc` command is used to add the `.sys` driver

**Background:**
I created an kernel driver for a few colleagues and would not pay over 200$ yearly for an official certificate to signing the driver or enable the testsigning because it makes problems.

If the self-signing is not possible, did exist any bypass methods or other ways to do this? Without affecting the other computers?

Comment: Self-signing is not possible without testsigning enabled.

Comment: How openhardwaremonitor does this? The app create the .sys driver file with an expired certificate. I am not familiar with C#.

Comment: That file is signed by a certificate that chains back to a root certificate authority (GlobalSign).

Comment: This means, when i use an outdated certificate, i can signing an kmdf driver?

Comment: No, the certificate date has nothing to do with it.

Comment: What does no mean? No i can not signing with the outdatet certificate or yes, you can signing because the date has nothing to do with it?
When i one time buy a certificate for 200$ and can it use for my entire life then i am thinking to buy one.. The valid date has for me no reason.

Comment: You cannot sign a file with an expired certificate.